# Visual Basic MySQL Login : "Error in your SQL Sytax"

Tags: mysql, authentication

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your mySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near "" at line 1"

^^when I press login (though testing the connection through the application works no problem)

**Immediate Log**:

> "A first chance exception of type
>   'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll"

**Login Button Code**

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MySQLConn = New MySqlConnection
        MySQLConn.ConnectionString = "server=IP;userid=USER;password=PASS;database=DATABASE"
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
        Try
            MySQLConn.Open()
            Dim SqlQuery As String
            SqlQuery = "select * from database.loader where uname='" & uname.Text & "' AND pword'" & pword.Text & "'"
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(SqlQuery, MySQLConn)
            READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
            Dim count As Integer
            count = 0
            While READER.Read
                count = count + 1
            End While

            If count = 1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Uname/pass correct")
            ElseIf count > 1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Uname/pass incorrect")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Uname/pass incorrect")

            End If

            MySQLConn.Close()

        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MySQLConn.Dispose()

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Consider the possibility that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, for example, if `uname.Text` returns "`1' OR 1=1 -- `", or something more nefarious, ala Little Bobby Tables [http://xkcd.com/327/](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look right:

```
pword'" & pword.Text & "'"
```

Looks like you want something like this:

```
pword = '" & pword.Text & "'"
     ^^^
```

Comment: Haha, I love when you look at it so closely the obvious is invisible, thanks man!